# JSP - Get Add result in the same form/same page

Tags: java, jsp, http, servlets

I am trying to figure out how to add two nubers and have the result on the same page using Java/jsp (in this case - in the "result" area in the jsp. I tried with session attribute, but there is still something wrong with my code...
I do not want to use javascript etc, but "pure java" only :)

Could you help:

Servlet:

```
package wprowadzenie;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/AddServlet.html")
public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer getInt(String s) {
    try {
        Integer a = new Integer(s);
        return a;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void serviceRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException     {

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/add.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

    String no1 = request.getParameter("a");
    String no2 = request.getParameter("b");
    Integer one = getInt(no1);
    Integer two = getInt(no2);

    if (one != null && two != null) {
        int result = one + two;
        System.out.println(result);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("result", result);

    }

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException     {

    System.out.println("get");
    serviceRequest(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("post");
    serviceRequest(request, response);
}

}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="AddServlet.html" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="a" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="b" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Result:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="result" disabled="disabled"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="add"/>



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure, but I`d like to/have to use Servlets/JSP only... There must be a simple way to do it with java only

Comment: set the value in request scope and then retrive it in jsp through jstl

Answer (score 1):

here it is your revised code

```
package wprowadzenie;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/AddServlet.html")
public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer getInt(String s) {
    try {
        Integer a = new Integer(s);
        return a;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void serviceRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException     {

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/add.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

    String no1 = request.getParameter("a");
    String no2 = request.getParameter("b");
    Integer one = getInt(no1);
    Integer two = getInt(no2);

    if (one != null && two != null) {
        int result = one + two;
        System.out.println(result);
        request.setAttribute("result", result);

    }

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException     {

    System.out.println("get");
    serviceRequest(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("post");
    serviceRequest(request, response);
}

}
```

your JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="AddServlet.html" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="a" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="b" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Result:</td>
             <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${request.result ne null}">
                        <td><input type="text" name="result"  value="${request.result}" /></td>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>

                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="add"/>



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, it does not work... The "result" as an attribute is not visible at all... The "when test" fails so the "otherwise" will be done. Why?

Comment: you don't need ${request.result} just ${result}

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="result" disabled="disabled" value ='<% out.println(request.getParameter("a") + request.getParameter("a")); %>' />
```

on submit, use same page and using above kind of code calculate and print result in result text field

Comment: As those are strings the result will be (eg. a = 12, b = 12) 1212 not 24. I could parse it to an int withinh jsp but I'd like to have the logic int the class not jsp...

Comment: if you want to use servlet then you need to calculate and pass veriable and then out.print it in jsp
or
if you dont even want to print from jsp, then you have to throw html from your servlet

Comment: plus obviously it will give 1212 as result you need to use something like Integer.parseInt to convert it

Comment: What I want is to leave the java code in the servlet class. I can do print in jsp, but parsing should be done within AddServlet class.
If I could somehow pass the attributes to jsp via eg. "${result} it would be great, but "out.print" is also ok...

Comment: i believe your problem is solved or still you have any query....
if you have then we can solve it

if you are satisfied with answer please accept it..

thanks!!

Comment: Well I am using "request.setAttribute("result", result);" but the attribute will not be passed to the jsp and I have no idea why...